# R get the original index of data frame after subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to get the original index of a data frame after subsetting? It is being stored somewhere but I am not sure where and how to access it. I understand that there is a better solution if this is part of the algorithm design. I am just curious if anyone knows if it possible.

Example Scenario:

```
df = data.frame(atr1=integer(),atr2=integer())
for(i in 1:10) {
    df <- rbind(df,data.frame(atr1=as.integer(i),atr2=as.integer(i)))
}
View(df)
```

Note the far left side of output of View function in R studio will show the index (I am not sure how to post an image that only exists on my local machine). 
Create a data frame by taking subset of that original data frame:

```
df_subset <- df[which(df$atr1 > 4),]
View(df_subset)
```

The output of the View function doesn't index df_subset 1 to 6 as you would access them. The original indices 5 to 10 are maintained. I am curious if it is possible to accesses those indices in some fashion similar to:

```
df_subset[index,]$<some hidden attribute>
```

Comment: What is shown on the far-left of `View` is the "row name", and I put it in quotes because (1) not everything preserves them, and (2) it is commonly just a `character` vector of the row number. Unless you can ensure that everything you do on the frame does not replace it, you cannot rely on it. (Even then, I never consider row names as reliable, perhaps because I've been burned several times. `dplyr` and other tidy packages intentionally make no effort to preserve them.)

Comment: So you might be able to use it in situations like this, I would not rely on it in production code. If at all possible, pre-calculate a per-row unique id (using integers or UUIDs/GUIDs if a database is involved) and preserve those across all operations where you might need traceability.

Comment: BTW, your `for` loop is redundant and you should aviod calling `rbind` in a loop: `df <- data.frame(atr1=as.integer(1:10), atr2=as.integer(1:10)))`

Comment: This question out of general curiosity. I understand a primary key is a far better solution as far as design and would never use this design in production. For the given example do you know how of if it is even possible to access the character vector "row name" corresponding to row numbers?

Comment: `rownames(df)` gives the row names and if they are character representations of numbers then `as.numeric(rownames(df))` gives the numbers. I think the opinion expressed above about not using rownames is a bit overstated and applies more to some addon packages than to R itself.  dplyr is a major culprit here but the `tibble` package does have the `rownames_to_column` function.