# Conditional Subset, Manipulate and Replace

Tags: r

Following on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753823/subset-data-frame-multiple-conditions) I extracted the following data.frame

```
DF <- data.frame(A =c("One","Two","Three","Four","Five"),
                 B=c(1,1,2,2,3),
                 D=c(10,2,3,-5,5))

subset(DF, B %in% c(1,3))
     A B  D
1  One 1 10
2  Two 1  2
5 Five 3  5
```

but now I want to (for example) multiply the numbers by (say) five and replace them in the original data.frame

The following code

```
subset(DF, B %in% c(1,3))[,2:3] * 5
   B  D
1  5 50
2  5 10
5 15 25
```

gives me the numbers I want but how to I get them back to

```
      A B  D
1   One 5 50
2   Two 5  10
3 Three 2  3
4  Four 2 -5
5  Five 15 25
```

The answer is staring me in the face (ie the index numbers ... but how do I get to them)?

Comment: Try `DF[DF$B %in% c(1,3),2:3] <- subset(DF, B %in% c(1,3))[,2:3] * 5`

Comment: I was trying DF[as.numeric(rownames(subset(DF, B %in% c(1,3))[,2:3]),] <- subset(DF, B %in% c(1,3))[,2:3] * 5 based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261986/r-get-the-original-index-of-data-frame-after-subsetting which led me down the wrong path.  Thanks all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
DF[DF$B %in% c(1, 3), 2:3] <- DF[DF$B %in% c(1, 3), 2:3] * 5

DF
#      A  B  D
#1   One  5 50
#2   Two  5 10
#3 Three  2  3
#4  Four  2 -5
#5  Five 15 25
```